# Too many symbols to export in dll. Visual C++ LNK1189

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, dllexport

I am trying to turn our .lib project into multiple .dll projects.

Since Visual Studio allows at most 65k objects in one lib(otherwise error), I have separated the project into a lot of "smaller" ones.

However, the error is still there. I notice there are 400 classes in one project and each has fewer than 50 members. How can it exceed the limit 65k?

(error LNK1189: the limit of 65535 objects or members in a library has been exceeded.)

Maybe the solution is to further split the projects. Maybe I did something wrong.

1. All classes are exported.
2. A shared pre-compiled header file.

Is there any problem if I mix static and dynamic link in one solution?

Comment: I deleted my comment because I decided it wasn't helpful. I was trying to get at, does your count include member functions?

Comment: @TimSeguine yeah, it includes data/function members.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, did you clean + rebuild the project?

Comment: @bob I did it again just now to confirm.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. Looking for a way to list the exported objects, or even just the attempted count